# (Co)variance of product of a random scalar and a random vector

Tags: variance, covariance, random-variable

Given a random scalar $ x \in \mathbb{R} $ and a random vector $ Y \in \mathbb{R}^n $ that are independent, can it be said that:

$$ {\rm cov}(xY) = {\rm var}(x){\rm cov}(Y) + {\rm var}(x)E[Y]E[Y]^T + E[x]^2{\rm cov}(Y) $$

Thank you.

Comment: Is this for a course?

Comment: I would ask:  what is the meaning of $Cov(Z)$ when $Z$ is a vector? Do you intend $Varcov(Z)$ i.e. the variance covariance matrix?

Comment: @gung it is not. It is for the design of a Kalman filter (I am aware that the product of two variables is likely to be not normally distributed etc.).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The random variable $Z= xY$ is also a $n\times 1$ (column) vector. So
\begin{align}
{\rm Cov}(Z) &=  E(ZZ') - E(Z)[E(Z)]'  \\
             &=E[xY(xY)'] - E(xY)[E(xY)]' \\
             &=E(x^2)E(YY') - [E(x)]^2E(Y)[E(Y)]'
\end{align}
(we have used the assumed independence). Subtract and add $E(x^2)E(Y)[E(Y)]'$:
\begin{align}
{\rm Cov}(Z) = &E(x^2)E(YY')-E(x^2)E(Y)[E(Y)]'  \\
               &+E(x^2)E(Y)[E(Y)]'-[E(x)]^2E(Y)[E(Y)]'  \\
             = &E(x^2){\rm Cov}(Y) + {\rm Var}(x)E(Y)[E(Y)]'
\end{align}

Comment: If I proceed to add and subtract $E[x]^2{\rm cov}(Y)$ to where you left off: $cov(Z) = E[x^2]{\rm cov}(Y) - E[x]^2{\rm cov}(Y) + E[x]^2{\rm cov}(Y) + {\rm var}(x)E[Y]E[Y]^T = {\rm var}(x){\rm cov}(Y) + {\rm var}(x)E[Y]E[Y]^T + E[x]^2{\rm cov}(Y)$ I can get my original answer. Thank you.

Comment: I took the liberty of aligning your equations, Alecos. I think it makes them a little easier to read. If you don't like it, roll it back w/ my apologies.

Comment: @gung On the contrary, thanks for taking the trouble.